# TFDDataset detect changes after call to refresh

Tags: delphi, firedac

Is there any way of detecting whether the data in a TFDDataset has changed as a result of a call to the dataset's Refresh function?

Comment: For a dataset not modified by you I can think only about making a backup of the old resultset (as `Refresh` by default discards tuples from its internal storage).

Comment: Do you mean make a copy of the old dataset and then after refresh compare the copied dataset to the refreshed data?

Comment: Yes, that's I meant. What is your overall aim, btw.? Maybe there's another way to reach your goal.

Comment: Thanks. I have a complicated form which produces a tree view from a combination of tables. If one of the underlying tables is refreshed as a result of change by another user the app needs to be aware of the change and warn the user and provide the option to refresh and rebuild the treeview with the new data.

Comment: Which brings me on to the next question, which is what is the best way to compare the data in the old dataset to the new dataset. My initial view is to save the old dataset before refresh to a stream and then after refresh load the refreshed dataset into a second stream and then do a stream compare to see if they are identical or not.

Comment: That's an option. Depends if you just want to know if they differ. But still I feel that you're doing some kind of periodical polling. If that is so, could you consider [database events](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Database_Alerts_(FireDAC)), or even better a business tier? That's the best way to get notified when some data gets changed without wasting resources (of course depends if your database supports this feature or if it's worth building business tier for your application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nature of the [**Refresh**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Refresh) method is that it discards tuples fetched in its internal storage so after calling it you have no resultset for comparison. Hence the only way would be storing the original resultset before calling it.

But in your comment you've mentioned that your overall aim is to know whether a certain detaset has changed as a result of another user modification. That said, it sounds that you are polling the tables which is not efficient in general.

If that is so, I would suggest considering either [**database events**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Database_Alerts_(FireDAC)) (if your DBMS supports them) or better yet [**business tier**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic#Business_logic_and_tiers/layers) (ideally combined with the [**database events**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Database_Alerts_(FireDAC))). These events or tier would then generate event received by the client only when something in the database actually changes saving (potentionally lots of) empty round trips.